# Is too many controls on the designer a bad idea?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I am working on a winform app that requires about 65 radio buttons. I was reading on this forum someone saying that they would not put that many buttons on the designer. Instead have the button show at run time. The problem I had with that is the button were not lined up. Even inside a `Panel` but they were perfectly lined up when a dragged 65 radio buttons on the designer. Is it a bad Idea to have that many buttons on the design? if so why? Thank you.

Comment: 65 radio buttons is too much and it doesn't matter if you add them using designer or at run-time. why you don't use a `ComboBox` instead?

Comment: I thought it would be a better visibility for the end user. I have 65 paragraphs that represent contract clauses and based on the radio button that the end user picks that paragraph would show up. Example: radio button 32 represents clause 3.02.06. And so on.

Comment: You can choose any solution that you think better fits to your application :) But I think if you need a help about something like aligning your radio buttons, it's better to ask a specific question about it. The question is now too general and opinion based.

Comment: @Reza I appreciate your comment, I am here to learn, Please show me an example on how to line up radio buttons on a pannel.

Comment: Do you prefer them to be in one column or in multiple columns?

Comment: in one column please

Comment: So you can use a `Panel` and add radio buttons to the panel and set the `Dock` of radio buttons to be `Top`. Also you can use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and set a break after adding each radio button. Also you can use `TableLayoutPanel` with one column and add radio buttons to the rows.

Comment: I will go ahead and try your suggestion. I am new to this forum is there a way for me to give credit? if so how.

Comment: If you mean reputation, Yes, each vote on your questions make your reputation +5, each answer you accept +2, each vote on your answer +10, each post of you that accepted as answer +15.

Comment: I'll post an example for you. Hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 65 radio buttons is too much and it doesn't matter if you add them using designer or at run-time and you can use a `ComboBox` instead.

But if you think you need to use those radio buttons at run-time and the problem for you is aligning them in a column (as you said in comments) so:

- you can use a `Panel` and add radio buttons to the panel and set the `Dock` of radio buttons to be `Top`.
- Also you can use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and set a break after adding each radio button.
- Also you can use `TableLayoutPanel` with one column and add radio buttons to the rows.

**Example - Using Panel**

Add a panel to your form and set it's `AutoScroll` property `true`. Then write such code to add radio buttons dynamically to the panel:

```
//You can have radio texts in a list.
//You can load them from database, file or somewhere else, or define them for example here
var list = new List<string>
{
    "First radio text", "Second radio text", "Third radio text", "And so on"
};

this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var r = new RadioButton();
    r.Text = list[i];
    r.Tag = i;
    r.Name = string.Format("r{0}", i);
    r.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    r.CheckedChanged += r_CheckedChanged;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(r);
    r.BringToFront();
}
this.panel1.ResumeLayout(true);
```

And here is the hanlder for `CheckedChanged` event:

```
void r_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radio = (RadioButton)sender;
    //Use radio here
    //for example int radioIndex = (int)radio.Tag;
    //for example if(radio.Checked) ...
}
```

To access to radio buttons with name, you can use:

```
//find radio number 26
var radio = (RadioButton)this.panel1.Controls["r25"];
```

Also you can store radio buttons in a `List<RadioButton>` when you are adding them to the panel and access them later.

Comment: I know I know, I need more help. How and where do I put the if else statement. I put the first part of the code in button1 to generate the code to create the radio buttons, how do I call each radio button on button2? I also put the second part of the code in button2 ???? Thank you.

Comment: What `if` statement do you need and where do you want do you mean by call radio button?

Comment: I would like to be able to call any if statement on a radio button on button2

Comment: in other words if radio button1 is checked do this and so on

Comment: Maybe you need to write some codes in `r_CheckedChanged` and there you can use `radio` and it's `Checked` or other properties. Also since we set the name of radio buttons this way `r.Name = string.Format("r{0}", i);`,  wherever you want to access to any of radio buttons by name, you can use `var radio = (RadioButton)this.panel1.Controls["r0"];` (0,1,2,3... until list.Count-1) and use the `radio`. Also when adding radios to the form, you can have `var radios = new List<RadioButton>(); ` and add the radio to radios too , then you can access each radio simply by `radios[15]` for example.

Comment: I am almost there, but what ever radio button I check if fires the messagebox when it shoul only fire on the radio button I have selected.

Comment: void r_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var radio = (RadioButton)sender;

           if(radio.Checked)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("This is radio # 1");
           }
        }

      

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var radio = (RadioButton)this.panel1.Controls["r0"];
        }

Comment: `if (radio.Checked)` and then `MessageBox.Show(radio.Name)` for example. or if you really need the index of the radio, you should store the index in `Tag` property of radio when you are adding them , and then use it here.